# Redshift Count Number of Inserts/Updates

Tags: amazon-redshift

Is there a way to count the number of new inserts/rows in redshift? Ideally, I'm looking to put that into a statistics table to show the accumulation of data engineering efforts over time and what goes into keeping the lights on.

Comment: `INSERT` is not the only source of new rows.  Do you specifically mean `INSERT` only, or all new rows?

Answer (score 0):

Does STL_INSERT meet you needs?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_INSERT.html

Comment: Remembering though that this table only has records covering the most recent couple of days.

Comment: True dat.  You will want to collect this info daily and save it if you want to have longitudinal perspective.